# multiple where clause in report query ireport jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, orientdb

I want to generate a report chart for this data from two tables are required. So i have a query like this ( **Am using OrientDB** )

`select col1,col2 from (select col11,col22 from t1 where col11 = $P{col11}) where col1 = $P{col1} and col2 = $P{col2}`

When i run this report i will get following exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2 
>       at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)      at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.filter.OSQLPredicate.bindParameters(OSQLPredicate.java:366) 
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.assignTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.java:182) 
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.assignTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:435) 
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.executeSearch(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:417) 
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:388) 
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:64) 
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1163) 
>       ... 8 more

As my observation if i have single where condition i.e., either in subquery or outerquery it works, if it is having where clause in both they this is the exception thrown.

Comment: Your query doesn't seem valid. What's your goal?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it solves your problem, but use of aliases could maybe help you? For proper SQL alias on columns and table  :

select col1,col2 
from (  select col11 as col1, col22 as col2 
        from t1 where col11 = $P{col11}) as table
where col1 = $P{col1} and col2 = $P{col2}